# Manipulação de Consulta Sql em Select (Combo Multipla opção no Zend)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, zend

Bom dia,

Tenho um "Select" que me lista como opção tudo que estiver na tabela "areas", seguido da palavra "TODAS",

Logo a baixo de cada opção "area", é listado aquelas subáreas que tem ligação com a área.

Quando clicar em "áreas - todas", então o select automaticamente entende como todas subáreas, e as seleciona corretamente.

Está funcionando,

O problema ocorre quando não há subáreas e então aparece o nome da área seguido de "- todas",

O usuario seleciona essa opção e não entende o por que não funciona, mas é por que não existe sub-áreas,

**Eu preciso ocultar essa opção, para quando não existir sub-áreas**, mas não sei em que parte do código fazer a modificação.

Por que na segunda parte, onde mostra as sub-areas dentro da área, então já listou a paavra "área - todas".

o código é

```
private function getComboBoxGroup ()
{
    $group = [ ];

    foreach ( $this->getAreasTable ()->fetchAll () as $area ) {
        $group[$area->__get ( 'f_name' )] = [
            'label'     => $area->__get ( 'f_name' ),
            'data-area' => $area->__get ( 'f_id' ),
            'options'   => [ "ALL - {$area->__get ( 'f_name' )}" => "TODAS - {$area->__get ( 'f_name' )}" ]
        ];
    }

    foreach ( $this->getActionsTypesTable ()->fetchAll () as $action ) {

        if ( array_key_exists ( $action->__get ( 'f_area' ), $group ) ) {
            $group[$action->__get ( 'f_area' )]['options'][$action->__get ( 'f_id' )] =
                "[{$action->__get ( 'f_area' )}] " . $action->__get ( 'f_name' );

        }

    }

    return $group;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente verificar os dados

```
'options'   => [ "ALL - " . !empty($area->__get('f_name')) ? $area->__get ( 'f_name' ) : "alguma coisa" => "TODAS - " . !empty($area->__get ( 'f_name' ))? $area->__get ( 'f_name' ) : "alguma coisa" ]
```